# Id of item do not pass to the bootstarap modal in vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2

I have this code that does not pass the id of the item of array to the bootstrap modal
I need help with this because it takes too much time.

```js
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        lists: [
          {id: 1, name: "Name 1"},
          {id: 2, name: "Name 2"},
          {id: 3, name: "Name 3"},
          {id: 4, name: "Name 4"}
        ],
        delete_id: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
      passId(id){
       this.delete_id = id;
      },
      postDelete() {
        // this part return null
        console.log(this.delete_id)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- delete card item -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="delete_todo_item" tabindex="-1" user="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" user="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" >delete</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div style="margin: 0 auto;" class="text-center">
                        <h2 style="font-size: 15px;color: red;">sure_to_delete</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">close
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" @click="postDelete()">delete
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div v-for="item in lists" :key="item.id">
      {{item.name}}
      <i class="la la-trash" href="#delete_todo_item" data-toggle="modal" @click="passId(item.id)"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The issue is when I click on the delete button of the modal I return null in console.
My version of vue is 2.6.1.
I need to know if there is an issue. I really can't understand what is going wrong.

Comment: did you check that the item is passed correctly inside `passId` method?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes I do. It returns correctly in the log.

Comment: `data: {` should be `data(){`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim my fault but data in real code is just like what you said.

Comment: change to `<div v-for="(item, index) in lists" :key="index">` and see if it works.

Comment: @fevid Make no difference :(